# DexGuard: how to specify string encryption

Tags: android, string, encryption, dexguard

I am trying to get a basic understanding of how to specify string encryption using the command -encryptstring in the file dexguard-project.txt. For example, I see

```
-encryptstrings "android.content.pm.PackageInfo", 
"packageName",
"versionName",
"versionCode",
............ ,
"java.lang.String",
............
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's good example of the options in the DexGuard docs `{dexgaurd root}/samples/StringEncryption/dexguard-project.txt`

Here's the ones I tend to use.

```
#encrypt a specific string in a class
-encryptstrings class com.example.HelloWorldActivity {
    private static final java.lang.String MESSAGE;
}

#encrypt all strings in the class.
-encryptstrings class com.example.HelloWorldActivity

#specify the string itself, i.e any instance of "Hello world!" in your app. 
-encryptstrings "Hello world!"
```

Comment: I do not have access yet to the DexGuard docs, but I will soon. :) Thanks for posting. If I may, I might come back with more questions.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know yet what the code means (in details) but it does **not** mean that precisely the specified strings should be encrypted. (Here by string I mean any one item in the list following the *encryptstring* command.) Rather, it means roughly that the specified instance variables in the Android class PackageInfo should be encrypted, also all the instances of the Java class String should be encrypted. I am still looking for a better understanding.